# Comparison criteria with square root

Tags: calculus, analysis

I don't know with what can I compare $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$ , I tried to use $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ but since $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$$ I can't conclude that it diverges.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you say that $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ is eventually dominated by $c n$ for some $c > 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n \geq 1 \Rightarrow n+1 \lt 4n \Rightarrow n(n+1) \lt 4n^2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{n(n+1)} \lt 2n \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} \gt \frac{1}{2n},$ so $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the fact that $$n(n+1)=n^2+n = n^2+n+\frac14-\frac14=(n+\frac12)^2-\frac14$$ and so $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+\frac12)^2-\frac14}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+\frac12)^2}}>\frac{1}{n+\frac12}=\frac{2}{2n+1}>\frac{2}{2n+2}=\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: Or directly: $\frac1{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}>\frac1{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+1)}}=\frac1{n+1}$.